# Java: drawing a feathered shape from an Image on Canvas

Tags: java, canvas

I'm trying to make a game (2D) where a light source is supposed to light up the surrounding area. I currently have a neon sign with some letters on it, meaning that the light source is the shape of an oval (see image). I want everything to be pitch black except the surroundings of the sign[image]

I've currently made the following class:

```
public class bgReveal extends GameObject{

    private Image bg;

    public bgReveal(int x, int y, int radX, int radY, ID id, Image bg) {
        super(x, y, id);
        this.bg = bg;
        this.radX = radX;
        this.radY = radY;
    
    }

    public void update() {
    
        //this and render gets called 60 times each second
    
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
    
        //Here I'll draw the background using the elipse radius radX, radY to
        //cut out the elipse, then feathering the image
    
    }

}
```

I'll add this "GameObject" to a handler which will handle the updating and rendering of the image. Any idea on how to get this image thing working?

Comment: Draw an elipse on a buffered image using a Graphics object and then use a blur on it and draw the blurred image (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295929/java-blur-image)

Comment: And this is how you draw on a BufferedImage (http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/DrawingonaBufferedImage.htm)

Comment: Maybe you can use a `JLayer`. The section on [Responding to Events](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html#events) demonstrates how you can make a spotlight effect.

Comment: @IntoVoid Sorry, but I'm quite new to programing. How do I make sure that the image drawn is restrictred to the elipse I draw? Also, drawing the buffered image onto my canvas creates these black borders around it forming a square, and these borders start overlapping each other as I add light sources diagonal to each other.

Comment: I don't really know if that is even possible with the default graphics library. But what you could do is create an image in photoshop with a cutout circle in the middle. Use a falloff effect on the outline of the circle. And then draw this image on your scenery. Everything will be opaque except the area inside the circle where the image was transparent.

Comment: you could do something like this really easily using shaders. But ther are no shaders in java. So I would recommend makeing games inside unity or using opengl directly using something like libgdx in java. But this is way harder then just doing it in unity or godot